# Flutter - Save a local text file visible for user on Android

Tags: android, flutter, file-io

I'm trying to create a text file in a folder where the user can see for the file explorer apps of the mobile device, preferably in Documents folder.

Here is what I've till now (consider that we have all required permissions)

```dart
  final directory = Platform.isAndroid
      ? await getExternalStorageDirectory()
      : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  final filePath = '${directory!.path}/example.txt';

  File file = File(filePath);
  await file.create();
  await file.writeAsString('Some random text content');
```

After that I try to find this new file on my file explorer apps, but it seems to not exists and no error logs can been seen.

If you want see an example code I wrote this PoC -> https://github.com/felipeemidio/save-local-file-poc

What I've tried so far?

- If you try to execute `file.exists()` command it'll return `true`.
- Use `image_gallery_saver` lib to "download" my file results on an **error** for trying to save a `plain/text` file where should only be `image/*` files.
- Use `getExternalStorageDirectory(type: StorageDirectory.documents)` instead of `getExternalStorageDirectory()` changes nothing.
- `downloads_path_provider` lib does not support null-safety.
- If you set the directory path with the static value `'/storage/emulated/0/Documents/example.txt'`, is possible to see the file through Archives app, but will not show when you select the option to see all Documents files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try file path as

```
String filePath = '/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/example.text';
```

and don't forget to add permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: That is the same as the the last thing on my "I've tried" list in the discription

Comment: Instead of documents try downloads

Comment: Yes, it worked better. Could you edit your answer for me to set as correct?